# Как смогли обойти проверку и украсть средства?

Tags: php

Ребят, приветствую.
На сайте случалась ситуация, что один из пользователей смог обойти проверку и украсть средства.
После просмотра, увидел, что у пользователя в базе был **отрицательный баланс**.
Просьба, помочь и навести на мысль, заранее премного благодарен.

PHP:

```
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$_SESSION[USER_LOGIN]'"));// сессия присваивается после авторизации
    $balance = $user['balance'];//переменная с данными пользователя
    if ( isset($_POST['cashout']) ) {
        if ( $_POST['amount'] >= 10 ) {
            if ( $_POST['amount'] <= $balance ) {

                // Здесь скрипт выполняющий вывод средств и обновляющий баланс в БД

                $balance_res = $balance - $_POST['amount'];
                mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE `users`  SET `balance` = $balance_res WHERE `id` = '$us_id'");
                MessageSend(2, 'Средства успешно выведены', '/cashout');
            } else {
                MessageSend(1, 'Недостаточно средств', '/cashout');
            }
        } else {    
            MessageSend(1, 'Минимальная сумма 10 рублей.', '/cashout');
        }
    }
```

Форма:

```
<form action="/cashout" method="POST">
    Кому: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="payeer" placeholder="Payeer кошелек">
    Сколько: <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Сумма в рублях">
    <input type="submit" name="cashout" value="Cash Out">
</form>
```

Comment: УУУУ, Почитайте про SQL инъекции, скорее всего вместо логина был введён код

Comment: @Komdosh Причем здесь SQL инъекция, если баланс после вывода у человека был отрицательный. И он прошел проверку на 5-ой строчке. Я бы понял если бы там был баланс положительный.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, кроме инъекций пока в голову ничего не лезет, а историю транзакций сохраняете?

Comment: @Komdosh Вы имеете ввиду в БД? Да, и на платежке тоже осталась история этих выводов. Вот логи точно уже пропали. Только как история может помочь? Я туда пишу время, ID транзакции на платежке, кошелек и пользователь. Больше инфы нет.

Comment: А баланс сильно отрицательный стал?

Comment: @Croessmah ровно на ту сумму которую вывел.

Comment: @Croessmah выводов было несколько. 4 вывода по 5к и 1 вывод на 1к и баланс в итоге -21000 в базе так и висит.

Comment: "баланс после вывода у человека был отрицательный. И он прошел проверку на 5-ой строчке" – @ДанилСысоев, почему Вы решили, что: 1) он вообще "проходил" 5-ую строчку? 2) сбой был вызван в ходе работы именно этого скрипта?

Comment: инъекция может быть в коде выше, мы же его не видим. Вы не используете подготовленные запросы, это не гуд. Почитайте https://habrahabr.ru/post/148151/

Comment: @rugabarbo Потому что во всем проекте это единственное место где пишется транзакция в БД в таблицу cashout и вообще взаимодействует с API платежной системы.

Comment: @Jean-Claude я понимаю что-такое SQL инъекция, и не понимаю причем здесь она.

Comment: @ДанилСысоев, за счёт SQL-инъекции можно записать данные в таблицу `cachout` из кода, который не обращается к ней... Вы полагаете, что обошли именно этот код, потому что только этот код обращается к таблице `cachout`. Но именно это может оказаться ложной логической предпосылкой.

Comment: @rugabarbo хорошо, допустим записали в базу SQL инъекцией. А как обратились к API платежной системы, если оно находится только в этом условии?

Comment: Если указать в `$_POST['amount']` отрицательное число что будет?

Comment: Положительное, но это $balance_res а сравнивание с $balance она раньше идет.

Comment: А что за перменная с данными пользователя? Откуда она берётся?
 Код: `$balance = $user['balance'];//переменная с данными пользователя`

Comment: Хотя я поспешил  с ответом, в указанном коде отрицательное число не пройдет

Comment: @rugabarbo исправил. Это переменная которая в первой строке вызывается.

Comment: `$_POST['amount']` -  всегда проверяйте поступающие данные на допустимые значения. `$balance_res = $balance - $_POST['amount'];` - так делать нельзя

Comment: `if ( $_POST['amount'] >= 10 ) {` какие еще значения недопустимые? Или Вы имеете ввиду приведение типов?

Comment: вывод `$balance` через `var_dump` можете показать? строковое это значение, или же число

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov строка.

Comment: @ДанилСысоев если тип поля text, то ```is_numeric(`$_POST['amount']`)```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Неявное пребразование типов. Вот пример

```
<?php
$ammount=' 050w00';
$balance='40'; //<-- важно, что это строка
if($ammount>=10){
    if($ammount<=$balance){
       $balance=$balance-$ammount;
    }
}
print('balance:'.$balance);

balance:-10
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67714/discussion-on-answer-by-vitidev-------).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно подмена сессионных данных $_SESSION[USER_LOGIN] на другое имя с положительным балансом а вывод и update таблиц иже идет у Вас по id.

Не видно еще кода, когда в массив записывается стояния кошелька, $user['balance']

Comment: В программе код `$balance_res = $balance - $_POST['amount'];` идёт после проверки `if ( $_POST['amount'] <= $balance )`, поэтому Ваш ответ  показывает лишь одну из уязвимостей, но не объясняет отрицательный баланс...

Comment: Я тоже об этом думал и проверял людей с балансом больше 1к не было таких. Да и теоритически в проекте невозможен был пользователь с таким балансом.

Comment: @rugabarbo причем тут balance_res, он вычисляется уже после вывода средств, а осуществить вывод можно только если amount выше баланса пользователя с ником прописаны в сессии.

Comment: Добавил только что

Answer (score 0):

Может дело в том что у вас всё это не в транзакции?
Пользователь взял, подготовил запрос, 4 штуки, они всё в одну секунду проверили баланс, он положительный, и списали, вот у вас и минус

Comment: Между транзакциями интервал больше минуты

Comment: Объясните, как вы это достигли?

Comment: @ДанилСысоев И этот вектор атаки тоже возможен, особенно если время последней транзакции хранится в базе.

Comment: При таком типе атаки мы не сможем получить отрицательный баланс.

Comment: @vitidev хорошо, я учту этот факт, и что-нибудь покумекаю сверху.